# NodeJS design pattern: simple http router

Tags: node.js, design-patterns

I'm working on a nodeJS router and was wondering if there's a faster/better approach when it comes to routing http requests with nodeJS.

I do not want to use a router from some kind of framework, I want to build it myself.

```
var servletRoutes = {
    "/grid/api/proxy" : statusServlet,
    "/grid/register" : registerServlet,
    "/grid/unregister" : unregisterServlet,
    "/selenium-server/driver" : rcRequestHandler
};

var parseIncoming = function(req, res, cb) {
    var srvUrl = url.parse(req.url.toString(), true);
    var servlet, route;
    if (servletRoutes[srvUrl.pathname]) {
        servlet = servletRoutes[srvUrl.pathname];
        return servlet.handleRequest(req, cb, res);
    } else {
        // slower lookup of routes
        for (route in servletRoutes) {
            if (route === srvUrl.pathname.substring(0, route.length)) {
                servlet = servletRoutes[route];
                return servlet.handleRequest(req, cb, res);
            }
        }
    }

    return cb("Invalid endpoint");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var app = express();
app.use( '/', app.router );
app.post('/grid/api/proxy', statusServlet,);
app.post('/grid/api/register', registerServlet,);
...
app.use( function ( request, response ) {
    response.send( 404 );
});
app.use( errorHandler );
```